# How do I set ng-option model to the value of an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm pulling in an array of objects as `$scope.templates`.  I'd like to be able to set `$scope.item.steps` (my select model name) to the value of `template.steps` for the selected option in my ng-options array.  Is there an easy way to do this without having add extra controller logic?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="template.name for template in templates" ng-model="item.steps">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202913/beyers) answered it spot on. Just one suggestion would be to use **`track by`**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="template.steps as template.name for template in templates track by template.id" ng-model="item.steps">
```

It doesn't *need* to be `template.id` but you should track some unique identifier. This helps with a number of performance/rendering issues.

**Definitely necessary if:**

- you are going to be updating item.step outside of this input
- you have a dynamic options collection (in this case `templates`)

Related: [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) , [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the `select as label for value in array` syntax:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="template.steps as template.name for template in templates" ng-model="item.steps">
```